# Unable to install a widget I downloaded and edited

Tags: mojave, security, dashboard-widget

I use Mojave with Dashboard switched on. I downloaded a dashboard widget file and edited a html file inside it by "showing package contents". I just wanted to change the font size of some text and did that in the HTML file. But after saving the file and trying to install the widget MacOS shows an error "This package has an error and needs to be moved to trash".

Is there a way to install a third party widget after changing a file in it?

Comment: I assume it did work before the change? Did you check whether there is maybe a typo in your code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking that. Yes it works if I install it before modifying. And I double checked typos etc Just changed font-size from 12 to 16 in the html. It doesn't work even if I just modify and un-modify a file. So I guess MacOS security is checking some signature of the package and not allowing installation.